# Displaying the same component in multiple sizes

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

On the welcome screen of my website, I have a large image with a welcome message floating around it. Everything is sized using `rem`. I now realize that I want to use a miniature copy of this image and text as a logo to appear inside a small-sized div in the corner in all screens of the website.
I could translate all the sizes to `em`, but is there a better solution?

Comment: why not just try change it to `em` and give it a shot and see how it goes for the entire site :) Otherwise you can design a component with a prop `width`.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what exactly you want. Seems like you could use absolute positioning. And btw em is a powerful unit for margins and paddings.

Comment: Could use `transform: scale(1);` 1 is normal size .5 half 1.5 1.5x size

Comment: @JelleStekelenburg This seems to be the easiest approach and it works (used in conjunction with `transform-origin`), but I am not sure whether it is the right use case for `transform`.

Comment: Depends. Scale is ofcourse a bit anoying when it comes to paddings etc. Maybe try giving it padding on its own?